# Is there a way in VHDL to external name reference a generic?

Tags: vhdl

A module lower in the hierarchy has integer generics. I want to override the generic inside this automatically generated code from my testbench by using VHDL `force` command. The problem is that whatever I do the simulator gives error message:

```
# ELAB2: Fatal Error: ELAB2_0127 W_PROBE_FPGA.vhd (136): Incorrect object class for external name: '<<probe_fpga_inst.SPRINT_PROBE_TOP_LEVEL_0.SYNTHESIZE_ACCELERATION_DAQ>>'.
```

I tried this code:

```
alias SYNTHESIZE_ACCELERATION_DAQ is <<signal probe_fpga_inst.SPRINT_PROBE_TOP_LEVEL_0.SYNTHESIZE_ACCELERATION_DAQ : integer>>;
```

With keywords signal, variable, constant and also empty. But none of them work. What do I do now?

Comment: `Incorrect object class` implies that the external name referenced is not a signal. If it is a generic, then it is a `constant`, not `signal`.

Comment: A **force** in VHDL (-2008+) affects either a signal driving value or signal effective value. Lacking a [mcve] this appears to be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). The alias name provides no insight even assuming DAQ is an acronym for Data AcQuisition. *What do I do now?* See [ask].

Answer (score 2):

You can see from @Tricky's response that external names are not going to get the job done.  However, you can use a configuration declaration to do it.

Configuration declarations can be hierarchical and can set generics as shown below.   Below for entity/component Block1 (whose instance label is Block1_1) the value for generic G1 is changed to NewValue.  Note for generic G2, the mapping done preserves the value.

```
library LIB_CHIP ; 
configuration CfgLower of TbCHIP is
  for StructTb
    for CHIP_1 : CHIP 
      use entity LIB_CHIP.CHIP (StructChip) ;
      for Structural
        for Block1_1 : Block1
          use entity work.Block1(RTL) 
          generic map (G1 => NewValue, G2 => G2) ; 
        end for ; 
      end for ; 
    end for ; 
  end for ;
end CfgLower ;
```

For synthesis, you would need to "propagate up generics" by putting a lower level generic on a higher level design until you get to the level at which you are using the higher level component.

```
entity NextHigher is
  generic (G1 : integer ) ; 
  port (...) ; 
end entity NextHigher ;
architecture RTL of NextHigher is

begin
  Lower_1 : Lower
    generic map (G1 => G1) -- mapping Generic from NextHigher to Lower
    port map (. . . ) ; 

  . . . 
end architecture RTL ; -- NextHigher
```

Comment: Thanks Jim, however, heresay is that configurations are not supported for synthesis code i.e synthesis tools do not support them. Is this true in your understanding?

Comment: I would not expect a synthesis tool to support them.   I would not expect a synthesis tool to like external names either though.

Comment: For Synthesis if you need to change a generic value, it would need to be propagated up to the point at which you were going to change it.   I have seen people do this with record structures - however, that is a complexity that I try to avoid.

Comment: No I mean that synthesis tools not supporting VHDL configuration. I know that synthesis tools do not support external names. This has been confirmed.

Comment: I added to the post above to explain how to propagate up generics for synthesis - without configurations